# Angular orderBy is not responding

Tags: angularjs

I have an array obj as following:

```
$scope.list = [
    {
        _id: "1111",
        desc: "Desc 1",
        image_url: "uploads/name-1.jpg",
        name: "Name 1",
        sequence: 0 
    },
    {
        _id: "1112",
        desc: "Desc 2"
        image_url: "uploads/name-2.jpg",
        name: "Name 2",
        sequence: 2 
    },
    {
        _id: "1113",
        desc: "Desc 3",
        image_url: "uploads/name-3.jpg",
        name: "Name 3",
        sequence: 3 
    },
    {
        _id: "1114",
        desc: "Desc 4",
        image_url: "uploads/name-4.jpg",
        name: "Name 4",
        sequence: 4 
    },
    {
        _id: "1115",
        desc: "Desc 5",
        image_url: "uploads/name-5.jpg",
        name: "Name 5",
        sequence: 0 
    },
    {
        _id: "1116",
        desc: "Desc 6",
        image_url: "uploads/name-6.jpg",
        name: "Name 6",
        sequence: 0 
    },
];
```

and HTML

```
<span data-ng-repeat="item in list  | orderBy: 'sequence' ">{{item.sequence}}</span>
```

I've also tried `orderBy: '-sequence'`, `orderBy: 'sequence':true`. `orderBy: 'sequence':false`. But the order doesn't seem to update!

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: You have missing commas (on lines with `desc` property) and therefore syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is badly defined, as you're missing commas.

The code you posted does work, [see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ck7m8zUY8zSbI1FiqzYO?p=preview).

```
<span ng-repeat="item in list  | orderBy: 'sequence' ">
    {{item.sequence}}
</span>
```

Comment: ive updated the list, its not the actual list, i just typed some filler data but mustve forgotten the comma. thanks for the plunkr. it must have been something else causing the issue.